# My docker container with cloudera quickstart image desapears few seconds after I started

Tags: docker

I'm trying to execute a docker container with a Cloudera quickstart image in Windows 11.

I followed the tutorial in the page https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/.

When I execute the image from docker dash I received the error "Error invoking remote method 'docker-run-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - No command specified".

There is no log.

My Docker app is updated - Docker Desktop 4.5.1 (74721).

I did the image download from command:

```
docker pull cloudera/quickstart:latest
```

---

```
REPOSITORY               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
docker/getting-started   latest    bd9a9f733898   3 weeks ago   28.8MB
cloudera/quickstart      latest    4239cd2958c6   5 years ago   6.34GB
```

The container is created

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
4242480d0804   4239cd2958c6             "/usr/bin/docker-qui…"   5 minutes ago   Exited (139) 4 minutes ago             charming_buck
6b3e7313b8e9   docker/getting-started   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 days ago      Exited (0) 2 hours ago                 interesting_ptolemy
```

I've seen some similar questions with some answers like change the *.wslconfig* file, I did it but I got same error.

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "8GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}
```

But with no result. Is there anyone could help me?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: to start the container run

```
docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -it cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

**Note 1:** `/usr/bin/docker-quickstart` is provided as a convenience to start all **CDH services**, then run a Bash shell. You can directly run `/bin/bash` instead if you wish to start *services manually*.

**Note: 2** A container will die when you `exit` the `shell`, but you can disconnect and leave the container running by hitting `Ctrl+P -> Ctrl+Q`.